# Smart Pointer (auto_ptr) behavior

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

Not sure if someone has already asked this, but I see a strange behavior here:

I've declared two classes, one base and one derived with just one virtual method `display()`.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void display() {
        cout << "base class" << endl;
    }
};

class B:public A {
public:
    void display() {
        cout << "derived class" << endl;
    }
};
```

Now, in `main()`, if I try to declare an `auto_ptr` of `A` and assign it a new instance of `B`,

```
int main() {
    auto_ptr<A> *a = (auto_ptr<A>*)new B();
    a->display();
}
```

I get this error on compiling:

> "`'class std::auto_ptr<A>'` has no member named 'display'"

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone explain the behavior?

Comment: I’ve fixed your formatting. You can use the preview when writing the question to see whether the format is correct; in your case, you mixed up quoted text with source code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks.  I'll take care of this next time.  I'm back at StackOverflow and to C++ programming after a long time and hence these errors :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a pointer to an `auto_ptr`. An `auto_ptr` is an object that works like a pointer, so you don't need to add a `*`.

You probably want:

```
auto_ptr<A> a(new B());
a->display();
```

Although I must recomment either Boost's smart pointers (`scoped_ptr` and `shared_ptr`) or C++11's `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto_ptr<A> *a = (auto_ptr<A>*)new B();
```

That is doing something very strange. If you want to create an object and use a smart pointer to manage it, then initialise the smart pointer with a pointer to the object:

```
auto_ptr<A> a(new B);
a->display();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why did you write `auto_ptr<A> *a`? It should not be like that. Therefore you are getting this error. It should be `auto_ptr<A> a(new B);`. Read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/auto_ptr/) how it works.